# Unix time in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

Is it possible to get the current UNIX timestamp with sql?

Answer (score 10):

Try [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```